# Forward declarations causing designer problems in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio, c++-cli, visual-studio-2012

I am migrating a small C++/CLI project from VS2008 to VS2012, and have run into a frustrating issue.

In my MainForm I have two forward declarations of classes. These are in between the namespace declaration, and the MainForm declaration.

These two forward declarations cause the designer to complain with the error "The class MainForm can be designed, but is not the first class in the file. Visual Studo requires that designers use the first class in the file. Move the class code so that it is the first class in the file and try loading the designer again."

Any ideas on potential solutions? I tried putting the references in the class, and after the class and neither had positive results.

Comment: Maybe forward declare `MainForm` before the other forward declarations?

Comment: Haha, genius and so simple. Worked beautifully. Thank you.

Comment: Mind if I make it a real answer?

Comment: Please do. Will be happy to accept.

Comment: This only goes wrong if you declared a complete class instead of a forward declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio just needs to see the `MainForm` class first. The easiest way to do this without adding includes would be to forward declare `MainForm` itself:

```
namespace TheNameSpace
{
    ref class MainForm;
    // Other forward declarations go here

    public ref class MainForm
    {
        //Full class declaration goes here
    };
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Still the same error. Event after cleaning and rebuilding. Notice that my "MainForm" inherits from System::Windows::Form::UserControl. Does it matter?

Comment: One would have hoped that after 8 years Visual Studio would be able to handle this, but no, in Visual Studio 2019 this is still a problem...